# Creating Quorum queue with ha-mode=all

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I want to apologize in advanced, but I am not very experienced with MassTransit.
I need help creating quorum queue and set "ha-mode" of the queue to "all" for MassTransit 8.0.15

My code is:

```
services.AddMassTransit(mt =>
{
    mt.AddConsumer(typeof(FileConsumer))
          .Endpoint(e => { e.Name = "my-queue"; e.InstanceId = ""; });

    mt.UsingRabbitMq((context, rmq) =>
    {
    rmq.Host(rabbitMqHost, host =>
   {                        
    host.Username(userName);
    host.Password(password);                        
   });

   rmq.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
   });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

I tried with adding:
rmq.SetQueueArgument("x-queue-type", "quorum");
rmq.SetQueueArgument("x-ha-mode", "all");

but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `ha-mode` is only for classic queues. Quorum queues are completely different. You can configure receive endpoints to use quorum queues by adding a configure endpoints callback:

```cs
mt.AddConfigureEndpointsCallback((name, cfg) =>
{
    if (cfg is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator rmq)
        rmq.SetQuorumQueue();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Chris,
Your solution is perfect. The queue was created as quorum.
I tested it with three nodes and it works fine as I expected.
Thank you once again.